# How to parse back a string.Format output?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing

I have a file containing data produced by string.Format(), one per line, something like:

```
Class1 [ Property1 = 123, Property2 = 124 ]
Class2 [ Property4 = 'ABCD', Property5 = 1234, Property6 = 10 ]
Class1 [ Property1 = 2, Property2 = 3 ]
Class2 [ Property4 = 'DEFG', Property5 = 2222, Property6 = 19 ]
```

and so on...

I need to parse them back to obtain the instances of the classes.

Given that I have the original string.Format template used to produce such lines, **what's the fastest way to obtain back the original values so that I can build back the instances of `Class1` and `Class2` (for fast here I mean in terms developer's time)?**

PS: I can rely on the fact that all input strings are "well formed" according to the template.
PPS: I know that using JSON would make this simpler, but right now I can't. Moreover I know [Irony](http://irony.codeplex.com/) too, but I'm looking for something even faster (if possible).

Comment: And **specific** question is...?

Comment: How can I do such parsing... @Adriano : "what's the fastest way to obtain back the original values so that I can build back the instances of Class1 and Class2"

Comment: Giacomo, I was kind ironic. Question is pretty too broad if you do not provide your own code. I guess a tokenizer would work quite well here (with little bit of Reflection if you don't need something with "esoteric" performance).

Comment: To me, it looks quite specific: I provided an example to be parsed and I said that I have the templates passed to string.Format. I can write the code by myself, I just need some hints, since using irony is a bit overwhelm.

Comment: Did you mean a deserialization?

Comment: @NK yes, you can consider it as a deserialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your strings don't contain special characters, here's a start:

```
        var str = "Class1 [ Property1 = 123, Property2 = 124 ]";
        var m = Regex.Match(str, @"^(?<name>[^ ]+) \[ ((?<prop>[^ ]+) = (?<val>[^ ,]+),? )+\]$");
        Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["name"].Value);
        for (var i = 0; i < m.Groups["prop"].Captures.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["prop"].Captures[i].Value);
            Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["val"].Captures[i].Value);
        }
```

Output:

```
Class1
Property1
123
Property2
124
```

If your strings do contain special characters, you could go with even more complex regular expressions, or you need to parse your string character by character, in a state machine. The first case I cannot answer because you haven't provided exact rules what your strings can or can't contain. The second case I cannot answer because it's too complex.

Comment: No special characters. I thought about regex, but I hoped that a reverse of string.Format exist.